# Creation of fitness function for objective function with multiple, non-related constraints?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

**Summary:** How can I create a fitness function for a problem where I want to minimise one quantity (mass), but have constraints on other quantities (max acceleration and max velocities need to be less than a certain value)? Also, how would I get a genetic algorithm to actually vary parameters within a model (will explain more below).

**Context:** I am working on a project (rocket simulation) where I want to land a rocket safely, minimise mass of fuel used, and ensure that the max. accelerations and velocities are safe for the astronauts inside. The only thing that is controlled by the user is the form of the desired velocity at a given height: v = f(x). Perhaps, I can break down my question into the following parts:

1) Without inputting a form for f(x), would it be possible to have a genetic algorithm form its own 'optimised' function?

2) If it is possible, how would I implement a cost function? 
- some searching led me to something of the form:
Fitness = (weight)*mass_fuel_left - penalty for each constraint infringed

3) If I am able to get a function, how would I actually get the program to run through different iterations?

(This is for either MATLAB or Python - I already have working code for the simulation, but just wanted to explore this possible extension)

I would really appreciate any help or some direction to useful sources.

Comment: Some questions to add context: what happens if Max acceleration and Max velocity exceed the limit? So you want to genetically select a function f(x) which lands the rocket or want to tune a specific function? What about your mutation function? What about breeding function? Finally how do you calculate the fuel used?

Comment: Thank you for your response. If max acceleration & velocities exceed the limits, then nothing happens within the code, but I consider it a failure. I would like for the function to select a function f(x). With the mutation and breeding function, I haven't thought that far yet but will look into it asap. The fuel was a calculated by: Fuel_left = Initial_fuel - burn_rate*time

Comment: The point is you put the `penality for each constraint infranged` in your fitness function, but that's no good IMHO because it mixes the quality of a successful function with unsuccessful functions and it tilts all the rankings. That fuel calculation function seems a little sloppy as it doesn't take in account the actual consumption based on the energy-work needed to break the ship.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your system works, but I imagine you just feed the program with a given function and it simulates the landing keeping track of important parameters such as fuel mass used, max acceleration and velocity right? So like the simulation itself is some sort of black box you don't know how actually works under the hood.
If so you basically just come out with a function and feed it to the simulation and it tells you if it passed and how much fuel was left in the tank.

In this case your fitness function is quite simple:

```
function fitness(Fx) {
    result = simulate(Fx);
    if(!result.pass) return -1;
    return result.fuelLeft;
}
```

This is just pseudo code, basically it takes as input the function f(x) which is our genetic algorithm specimen, then run the simulation with it: if the simulation doesn't pass (astronauts die) then the specimen is no good (please keep in mind killing people is not a penalty, it's something that should **never** happen, so when they die the specimen should not even run for selection), if the simulation passes then the best functions are the ones that assure more fuel left in the tank. Doesn't matter if them astronauts get scrambled good, as long as they're alive you don't care much of the actual max acceleration/velocity experienced.

So the fitness function was easy peasy to come out with (as it often is as you should really keep it as simple as possible), but the hardest part is to come up with different functions that actually make sense and have a chance to better the previous generations.
Keep in mind when you use optimization algorithms you should first find a viable solution somehow, then you look "around" that solution to make it better.
What genetic algorithms do in specific is span a population of specimen with possible viable solutions and then select the best ones to determine the next generation. Next generations are determined by either mutating or breeding (or both) the previous specimen. Define mutation and breeding functions could actually be quite hard and I think it's off-topic here, but in the end your program steps should look like this:

1. Generate first generation somehow trying to come up with different functions that pass the simulation (even if badly)

Iterate the fallowing

2. Breed couples of functions coming up with new functions that have some of both the parents
3. Mutate the previous generation functions to make even more new functions
4. Run the simulation with each new function and rank them with the fitness function
5. Use some sort of discrimination to pick only "the best" functions for next breed/mutation steps. You can actually set this discriminant at each iteration so you can control your population, for example if too many specimen pass you'll find yourself with a lot of computation to do (probably useless), so you can make it more difficult to make it to the next gen by rising the required fitness, on the other hand if you find that results aren't getting better between iterations, maybe you are locked in some local max and should lean the requirements so that more different specimen are allowed to spawn and they may lead to better future solutions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to responsd. One question I have to start off with is: how would we generate some functions? From previous parts of the projects, I have functions that will work, but is there a way to let the computer do this from scratch?

Comment: That's also a whole different problem and quite hard in general. You could start with a linear function `f(x) = m*x + Vo` where `Vo` is the starting speed of the ship. Now to stop the spaceship after `H` meters (where `H` is the starting height) you'd have `0 = m * H + Vo` in this last equation the only variable is `m` so you can find it. Finally check if it's a viable solution.